# Are rgb changes affected by monitor response time?

Tags: display, rgb

If I'm not wrong, response time on monitors just has to do with how dark or light the image is. In that case, if a monitor has a dark blue frame followed by a light red frame and response time is 10ms, will the 2nd frame turn dark red at its start and take 10ms more to get lighter? Or does it also take 10ms to fully go from blue to red?

Answer (score 0):

> f I'm not wrong, response time on monitors just has to do with how dark or light the image is.

That is correct because brightness is the only property each subpixel has.

> In that case, if a monitor has a dark blue frame followed by a light red frame and response time is 10ms, will the 2nd frame turn dark red at its start and take 10ms more to get lighter?

If the frame is blue, then all blue subpixels are illuminated and all red subpixels are turned off.  When the red frame arrives the blue subpixels will begin turning off and the red subpixels will begin turning on.  After about 10 ms this process will be mostly complete and the frame will be nearly the final color (red).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense